# Adding Outlook Inbox Email to multiple Salesforce Contacts by using the Sidepanel on Outlook

Tags: email, contact, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

By using of salesforce sidepanel in outlook,I am adding single inbox email to single salesforce contact only but my requirement is add inbox email to multiple salesforce contacts.Right now i am using salesforce for outlook 2.7 version.

Comment: When ever we send an email to Salesforce Contacts is added as a task in activity history,this thing will happens when we add in sending email BCC to "Email to Salesforce Address (emailtosalesforce@1umuq3lif1eoi6kkv401osnf2g73gff1vbcnx47e5iwlh4g475.e-5ullaeao.cs15.le.sandbox.salesforce.com)".is there any possibility without adding BCC in Outlook Email then added email in Salesforce Contact activity history....?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Salesforce for Outlook 2.7 doesn't have this feature. You may try 3rd party app from [Appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=outlook). These 3 apps have good reviews: [ContactMonkey](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4mHkEAJ), LinkPoint, Yesware